# Коммуникация между кастомными классами внутри модуля Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Какой лучший способ коммуникации между классами внутри кастомного модуля  в Битрикс? 
Пробовал создавать класс хранилища, а также использовать глобальные переменные, как указано [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic56527/) , однако никак не выходит. 
Задача простая - по событию сохранения товара в корзине выставить флаг и наименование товара, а затем с помощью OnAfterEpilog вывести название в консоль (при наличии установленного флага).

Comment: получилось реализовать коммуникацию с помощью $_SESSION. Чувствую, что это не лучший способ реализовать коммуникацию между классами.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, ошибка была в чем-то другом. Реализация статическим классом для обмена инфой между классами работает отлично.

Comment: поправка: статические члены класса не будут сохранять данные от страницы к странице. Для последнего случая лучше использовать сессию.